toolkit:AvatarView with images truncates the image
In my NET8 MAUI application, I have a ListView and in the ItemTemplate I what to display an image (from the internet) and the a Label. For that, I added Grid like that
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="dtp:ArticleBasic">
        <local:CustomViewCell>
            <Grid
            ColumnSpacing="10"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            RowSpacing="10"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.Padding>
                    <OnIdiom
                    x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                    Desktop="0,10,10,10"
                    Phone="10,10,10,10"
                    Tablet="10,30,10,0" />
                </Grid.Padding>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <toolkit:AvatarView
                BackgroundColor="{Binding LetterBackgroundColor}"
                BorderColor="Blue"
                BorderWidth="1"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                ImageSource="{Binding FeaturedImageUrl}"
                TextColor="{Binding LetterColor}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

                <VerticalStackLayout
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="{StaticResource ElementFontSizeNormal}"
                    Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Excerpt}" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>

                <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="2">
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </local:CustomViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>

When the app renders the list, the AvatarView displays the images but all of them are truncated on the right and bottom. I tried to change the HeightRequest or the WidthRequest, changed the first ColumnDefinition and the size of the images. The result is always like in the following screenshot.

Any ideas how can I fix it?

Use CollectionView with ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"

Based on your code you shared, I created a new demo and I could reproduce this problem.
To resolve this problem, you can add property HasUnevenRows="True" for your ListView:
    <ListView  HasUnevenRows="True">

Note:
I didn't know the code of CustomViewCell of your code, I just used normal ViewCell of ListView.

Yes, I have the HasUnevenRows in the ListView. CustomViewCell is a custom implementation to avoid the default (orange) background in Android (see this post)

Could you please share  a basic demo here so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?
